# Log4j2 json configuration doesn't write to file

Tags: java, json, logging, log4j2

I have this `log4j2.json` file under resources dir

```
{
    "configuration": {
        "status": "TRACE",
        "name": "App",
        "monitorInterval": "300",
        "appenders": {
            "appender": [
                {
                    "type": "Console",
                    "name": "STDOUT",
                    "PatternLayout": {
                        "pattern": "%m%n"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "RollingFile",
                    "name": "RollingFile",
                    "PatternLayout": {
                        "pattern": "%m%n"
                    },
                    "filename": "console.log",
                    "filePattern": "$${date:yyyy-MM}/console-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log",
                    "TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy": {
                        "interval": 24,
                        "modulate": true
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "RollingFile",
                    "name": "text-roll",
                    "PatternLayout": {
                        "pattern": "%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m %ex%n"
                    },
                    "filename": "info.log",
                    "filePattern": "$${date:yyyy-MM}/info-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log",
                    "TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy": {
                        "interval": 24,
                        "modulate": true
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "RollingFile",
                    "name": "json-roll",
                    "JsonLayout": {
                        "complete": true,
                        "compact": true,
                        "eventEol": true
                    },
                    "filename": "json.log",
                    "filePattern": "$${date:yyyy-MM}/json-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log",
                    "TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy": {
                        "interval": 24,
                        "modulate": true
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "loggers": {
            "logger": [
                {
                    "name":"Console Root",
                    "level": "debug",
                    "AppenderRef": {
                        "ref": "STDOUT"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name":"Console Output",
                    "level": "trace",
                    "AppenderRef": {
                        "ref": "RollingFile"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name":"Info",
                    "level": "info",
                    "AppenderRef": {
                        "ref": "text-roll"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name":"Json",
                    "level": "error",
                    "AppenderRef": {
                        "ref": "json-roll"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "root": {
                "AppenderRef": {
                    "ref": "STDOUT"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

While it does create those file but never writes to those anything. 
In the console.log, info.log is empty. But json.log has this content:

```
[

]

]

]

]

]

]
```

This is the console after starting the server for the log4j initialization:
[Gist of the console output](https://gist.github.com/shadow-fox/4c5af53db5c1a2a7c8a0)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain, but according to the only log line that isn't debug,

```
Log4j appears to be running in a Servlet environment, but there's no log4j-web module available. If you want better web container support, please add the log4j-web JAR to your web archive or server lib directory.
```

Is that jar present?

Comment: That jar is not present let me add this. But is it necessary to have ?

Comment: I have added the library but still no signs of any logs.

Comment: Make sure the configuration file is on your class path.

Comment: It is hence the console out put see is picking up the configuration file at this line https://gist.github.com/shadow-fox/4c5af53db5c1a2a7c8a0#file-output-log-L2